# Joining three mysql table including condition in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have very little knowledge about mysql table joining so i could not  solve it out the following problem .I have following three tables

```
  member table 

name           country
-----         --------
adam          bangladesh  

smith         england 

jon           United states

geric         bangladesh  

romio         england 

jelon         United states


table order

order_amount     country       approved 
-----        --------      -------
20            bangladesh      1

25            england         0

20            United states   1  

40            bangladesh      1

20            england         1

40            United states   0


table withdraw

withdraw_amount   country
--------------   --------
2                bangladesh  

4                england 

6                United states

8                bangladesh  

10               england 

22               United states  


my desired table


country_name   total_member  total order total paid                     
------------   ------------  ---------   ----------

bangladesh         2         60        10

england            2         20        14

United states      2         20        28
```

I would like to explain more in detail ,from member table  i would like to get the grouped country data so that i can tell how many members from a particular country.

From  order table i want to get the sum of order_amount where approved is equal to 1.That means i am trying to list the total approved order amount  from a particular country

From table withdraw i want to sum withdraw_amount so that i can know the total withdraw_amount from a particular country.

Finally my desired table will contain the country name and their  corresponding total_member , total order, total paid amount .Can anybody give me any idea about this difficult joining query?

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEYs. This is likely to prove problematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want. Using left join to match 3 querys

```
select * from (select country as country_name, count(name) as total_member  from members m
group by country) members left join 
(select sum(ammount) as total_order , country from orders where aproved = 1 group by country) ammounts on country_name = ammounts.country
left join
(select sum(withraw) as total_paid , country from withraw group by country) withraw on country_name = withraw.country
```

[see it in action here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/910ba/5)

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it works like a charm! in your query "select country as country_name, count(name) as total_member  from members m" i think you wrote the m after members by mistake,am i right?but it is not showing any error?as i mentioned earlier that i have very little knowledge about mysql so would you please explain  the query "ammounts on country_name = ammounts.country" ?1 more thing ,in the result there is one extra column which is  country,i know that i could hide the result from showing in a html table but which part of the query needs to be modified if i want to skip that extra column ?

Comment: Hi, the "m" is irrelevant. The "ammounts on country_name = ammounts.country" is the join condition. When I join 2 querys I'm saying which column is used to join them so country_name must be equal to ammounts.country. I also join again at the bottom. If you want to remove the columns replace the "*" at the begginning with the list of column names that you want, so instead of "*" you have "COUNTRY_NAME, TOTAL_MEMBER, TOTAL_ORDER, TOTAL_PAID". If the answer helped you don't forget to mark it as correct and/or upvote it

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer i tried before your saying to vote u up but feeling sorry as i don't have enough reputation to vote .  "ammounts on country_name = ammounts.country" i am not understanding that why not i'm using "orders on country_name = orders.country" as my table name was order ?

Comment: I created an alias for my query. So when i did `select sum(ammount) as total_order , country from orders where aproved = 1 group by country` if you watch right in front of it I called it `ammounts`. That's why I made the join with the alias for that query. BTW yes you can't upvote but you can mark the answer as correct